# Find the range of a complicated function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I need to find the range of the following function :

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt[4]{\frac{4x - 3y + 5}{3y-4x + 13}}$$

So my thoughts about it are first the bottom part $( 3y - 4x + 13 )$ must be greater than $0$ and then if this is true then the whole expression $(4x - 3y + 5/3y - 4x + 13)$ must be greater than $0$.

Am I mistaken somewhere in my thoughts? What is the right solution?

Can I use L'Hopital's rule to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! You are more likely to get a good answer if you ask clear questions. By "complex function" do you mean the variables can be complex numbers (using the square root of minus $1$) or do you mean a complicated function? Is this a function of two independent variables $x$ and $y$, or is $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Hi,thanks for responding.I have made a quick edit with respect to the notes you left.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you let $u=3y-4x+13$ then you get
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt[4]{\frac{18-u}u}$$

The value inside the root must be nonnegative. This happens when $u$ and $18-u$ have the same sign, so we must have $0<u \le 18$.

Check the range of $f(u)$ for those values of $u$ and you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks,I didn't pay enough attention for this pattern.